# Does Azure Databricks mounts S3 securely

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, databricks

Can't find in Databricks documentation explicit mention: does S3 bucket mounting to Azure DBFS uses SSL and how to check it?

I use AWS access keys to mount S3 bucket. I assume that connection is secure and private, but I can't find evidences of it.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does. But if you are worried, then just make sure your S3 bucket only allows SSL connections (that should be your default anyhow) https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/s3-bucket-ssl-requests-only.html

Comment: Thank you for advice. If would not be able to make sure that it uses SSL, than I'll apply this rule, as this is additional payed service.

Comment: I'm no AWS expert but my first google result tells me "S3 access points don't support access by HTTP, only secure access by HTTPS." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html So I would assume there is no way to access it without ssl

Comment: I confused with this `If you use third-party tools to interact with Amazon S3, contact the developers to confirm if their tools also support the HTTPS protocol.` https://aws.amazon.com/ru/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/secure-s3-resources/#:~:text=Use%20encryption%20to%20protect%20your,tools%20use%20HTTPS%20by%20default.&text=You%20can%20also%20enable%20default,%2DS3%20or%20SSE%2DKMS.